# Does angular-mdl work with SSR angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-mdl

I just upgraded my application to angular 9. Everything went well, but I am facing some problems when trying to run the SSR compilation.

```
\dist\server\main.js:6542
            __metadata("design:paramtypes", [MouseEvent]),
                                             ^

ReferenceError: MouseEvent is not defined
```

Is there something I'm missing? do you have an example of mdl-angular working on SSR (Universal) with Angular 9?

Comment: Are you using domino?

Comment: no, i'm not using domino

Comment: I'm not sure if angular-mdl supports using angular uni real. Maybe try using domino to mock browser objects

Comment: got this error on MdlSliderComponent
```setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void;
    onMouseUp(event: any): void;
    onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void;
    private updateSliderUI; 
```